# Entity framework 6.2.0 contains clause as where in not working propertly

Tags: c#, entity-framework, where-in

(update: sorry, I removed the AsEnumerable() code because when you use AsEnumerable the linq to sql object executes the sql query and brings the full table to memory which can have more than 10000000 rows and what I wolud like to do is to execute a where in clause)
I Am trying to create a “where in” clause in EF (id="EntityFramework" version="6.2.0") in c# to not bring the full table to memory but when used the code below, the select where in clause did not work I know that the DOCUMENT_ID’s that I use exist in the table:

```
    public partial class Table
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public long id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string DOCUMENT_ID { get; set; }

    public DateTime? xxx { get; set; }

    [StringLength(4000)]
    public string yyy { get; set; }

    public int? zzz { get; set; }

    public int? jjj { get; set; }
}


//this is a "patched" code

    using (BBDDCon BBDD = new BBDDCon())

    {
        //this list it is filled with a EF query
        idsuptate= new List<String>()  {"1","2","3"};


        var list_docs_procesed_error_aux = BBDD.Table.Where(d => (d.xxx != null || String.IsNullOrEmpty(d.yyy) || d.jjj != null));
//this one gets me 0 rows but it should bring 300 rows
        var list_docs_procesed_error= list_docs_procesed_error_aux.Where(d => idsuptate.Contains( d.DOCUMENT_ID.Trim())).ToList();
    }
```

I found a working solution but as enumerable brings the full table to memory and  as I said I would like to not do so:

https://forums.asp.net/t/1661185.aspx?Contains+method+not+working+in+Linq+to+Entities

Use AsEnumerable after the 'tableName' and before applying the 'where' method.

```
objDataContext = compareIndiaDataContext;
            objCProduct = objDataContext.Products.AsEnumerable().Where(db => alSelectedIDs.Contains(db.Product_BrandID)).ToList<Product>();
            return objCProduct;
```

¿Any thoughts? ¿colud be a bug?
Thanks a lot in advanced!

Comment: Why did you add `AsEnumerable()`? What "did not work"?

Comment: Sorry an error copy paste. The code is now updated fine.

Comment: @Gert Arnold The point was to not use AsEnumerable() but I tried to see if the code test was working. The problem is that is not a valid  response because I want to filter in sql server and not in the BL server due memory problems...

Comment: Have you solved this already?

Comment: Well yes, there is a bug in EF with spaces in PK but the code was fine in first place..

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
var list_docs_procesed_error_aux = list_docs_procesed_error_aux.Where(d=> idsuptate.Contains(d.DOCUMENT_ID.Trim())).ToList();
```

Comment: Sorry the code was wrong the.asenumerable was misscopied